# What should I take into account to make database connection handle thousands of simultaneous connections?

Tags: php, mysql, database, concurrency

I was given a task using PHP and MYSQL.
One of the requirements is that database connection must be able to handle thousands of simultaneous connections, requests from concurrent users. I know that it depends on server as well but my problem is that I do not know what I should take into account while writing the code. I can not use third-party libraries. Can you give me any advice?

Comment: Consider using connection instances from connection pool

Comment: advice, hire some one that knows how to do this.

Comment: Why can't you use third party code? Because that requirement isn't a good sign.

Comment: This isn't a programming question, it's about server and database administration.

Comment: Lots of CPU cores. Lots of SSDs, preferably in RAID 10. Lots of RAM